# about Retrofit get and post methods parameters

Tags: android

I read retrofit is good for client server communication.

In this I have some doubts.

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

In get method what is **group**, **id**, **users**, and what is `groupList(@Path("id") int groupId)`. What will it do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

When you build a new adapter for your interface with `Retrofit` you specify some server as endpoint. Let's say your endpoint is `http://www.example.com`. After that, when you execute `groupList` method, Retrofit will send a `GET` request to the `http://www.example.com/group/{id}/users`, where `{id}` placeholder will be replaced with a value you provided with `groupId` parameter during method call. So, this default parameter of `GET` annotation is just a path that should be appended to the server name and the value for placeholder is provided at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`/group/{id}/users` this your GET request url (BASE_URL + Your GET url) where your `id` will be replaced with `groupId` passed in your `groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);` method.

*Now your final request GET URL will be*

**BASE_URL + /group/{your groupId passed in method}/users**

finally response from server will be parsed to `List<User>` and returned.